# Spring Boot REST service deploy on Weblogic12c

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm deploy my application on oracle weblogic 12c.
My application use Spring Boot, Spring REST service and Jackson
All lib for jackson:
jackson-annotations.2.6.1.jar
jackson-core.2.6.1.jar
jackson-databind.2.6.1.jar
jackson-datatype-hibernate4.2.6.1.jar
jackson-datatype-hppc.2.6.1.jar
jackson-datatype-json-org.2.6.1.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310.2.6.1.jar

I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule

I think jackson-datatype-jsr310 confict in weblogic lib.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me to add this to the weblogic.xml :

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```